# App Script pull value from cell above and keep formula in cell above

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to pull the value from the cell above when a cell is blank, however, every-time I run my code it removes the formula from the cell above and makes it text.  Can someone help me figure out how to keep the formula intact?  Here is the code I utilized that worked with pulling a value down:

```
function fill_2(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UvBuVp9N866J-3677dXsPYYpZZRd7i1O4GIlPkBJWbA/edit#gid=713176516');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("All Client Log-ins");
  var tracts = ss.getRange("All Client Log-ins!F2:F").getValues();
  var allTractList = [];
  var title;
  var len = tracts.length;

  for (var row = 0; row < len; row++) {
    if (tracts[row] !='') {
      title = tracts[row];
      allTractList.push([title]);
      Logger.log(title);
    } else allTractList.push([title]);
  }

  Logger.log('allTractList' + allTractList);

  sheet.getRange("F2").offset(0,0,allTractList.length).setValues(allTractList);
  return allTractList;

}
```

Comment: Your code does not match your question

Comment: I used this code to pull contents to a blank cell from a cell above and it ran fine, I am new to script but assumed there is a way to pull in the formula from a cell rather than a value from a cell using the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think your code boils down to:

```
function fill_2(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1UvBuVp9N866J-3677dXsPYYpZZRd7i1O4GIlPkBJWbA');
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("All Client Log-ins");
  Logger.log(sh1.getRange("F2:F" + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(e => e));
  return sh1.getRange("F2:F" + sh1.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat().filter(e => e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried running the script to see if that produced results and I am seeing a 1 sec run that doesn't produce any results.  I also need to clarify it I accidently used getDisplayValues when I should have used getValues

Comment: You're the one with the data; debug it

Comment: I would if there was an issue with the code; however, it runs with no results therefore when I run a debugger it doesn't find anything.  I apologize for any ignorance in asking this question, I am simply just trying to learn. To clarify the issue I am trying to resolve, I am just trying to find a way to copy the value or formula form a cell above to a blank cell.